# In what sense $f_n:\mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1} \to \mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}$ is a projection map?

Tags: category-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Why the map $\mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1} \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}$ in the definition of p-adic ring of integer $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is called projection map ?

The definition is taken by inverse limit as follows:

> $\mathbb{Z}_p=\varprojlim \mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z},$ where homomorphisms are the projection maps $f_n:\mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1} \to \mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}$.

But I could not understand the projection map $f_n:\mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1} \to \mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}$.

In what sense $f_n:\mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1} \to \mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}$ is a projection map? what is the projected component in image set?

Comment: In practice, any surjection is liable to be called a projection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be thought of as a projection in the following sense. An element of $\mathbb Z /p^n \mathbb Z$ can be thought of as a number written in base $p$ with $n$ digits (including leading zeroes). Then arithmetic -- at least $+$ and $\times$ -- on these numbers is like ordinary arithmetic, except that you throw away any digits in a position higher than $n$ that appear.

Then this mapping "projects" $n+1$-digit numbers onto the last $n$ digits. For example, when $p = 5$ and $n = 4$, the mapping will take $21410$ to $1410$.

Comment: ... and $f_n$ is a projection map because it is idempotent i.e. $f_n^2=f_n$. For example, $f_4^2(21410)=f_4(1410)=1410$.

Comment: @Mees de Vries, Sorry, I did not understand the line   "An element of $\mathbb Z /p^n \mathbb Z$ can be thought of as a number written in base $p$ with $n$ digits (including leading zeroes)". Because this is a cyclic group and how do we represent its elements as base $p$ expansion? Please do little more and some elaborate on your example

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR, for example, if $p = 3$ and $n = 2$, then the elements of $\mathbb Z/9\mathbb Z$ can taken to be $0, 1, \ldots, 8$, which -- when written in ternary -- are $0, 1, 2, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22$. Then the mapping $\mathbb Z/9\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ then takes, for example, $21$ to $1$.

Comment: @MeesdeVries, thank very much

Answer (score 3):

Whereas Mees de Vries' answer is indeed a good way to think about this specific situation, and whereas Lord Shark the Unknown's comment is indeed a very general way to approach this, here is somewhat of a golden mean to see this:

One of the isomorphism theorems (in Wikipedia's numeration, the [third](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Third_isomorphism_theorem_3)) says that

> If $T \subseteq S \subseteq M$ are $R$-modules, then the quotient module $(M/T)/(S/T)$ is isomorphic to $M/S$.

In our situation $R=\mathbb Z$, $M=\mathbb Z$, $S=p^n \mathbb Z$, $T=p^{n+1} \mathbb Z$, this isomorphism identifies the "actual" projection -- if by that, we mean a quotient map --

$$\mathbb Z/p^{n+1}\mathbb Z \twoheadrightarrow (\mathbb Z/p^{n+1}\mathbb Z)/(p^n \mathbb Z/p^{n+1}\mathbb Z)$$

with the composite map

$$\mathbb Z/p^{n+1}\mathbb Z \twoheadrightarrow (\mathbb Z/p^{n+1}\mathbb Z)/(p^n \mathbb Z/p^{n+1}\mathbb Z) \simeq \mathbb Z/p^{n}\mathbb Z.$$

Comment: thank you very much for your nice answer. But I did not understand the  line #Mees de Vries's anawer "An element of $\mathbb Z /p^n \mathbb Z$ can be thought of as a number written in base $p$ with $n$ digits (including leading zeroes)." Can you explain how the elements of a finite cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}$ can have base $p$ expansion or representation?

Comment: Elements of $\mathbb Z$ have base $p$ expansions. Projecting them to $\mathbb Z/p^n$ truncates such an expansion after $n$ digits.

Comment: thank you for your help